# Urn contains $i$ white balls and $(3-i)$ black balls. Let $T$ be the time there are only white balls left in the urn. Find $E[T]$

Tags: probability, markov-chains, expected-value, polya-urn-model

An urn contains $i$ white balls and $(3-i)$ black balls. Let $T$ be the time there are only white balls left in the urn. Find $E[T]$.

At each time step we choose a ball at random and replace with a white ball.

So I tried to find a pattern:

if $i = 3$ the $E[T] = 0$ trivially,

if $i = 2$ then $E[T] = \frac{1}{3}\cdot 1 + \frac{2}{3}(1 + E[T]) \implies E[T] = 3$

If $i = 1$ then we have $E[T] = \frac{1}{3}(1+E[T]) + \frac{2}{3}(1+E[T\mid i = 2]) \implies E[T] = 12$

And lastly if $i = 0$ then $E[T] = 1(1+E[T \mid i = 1] \implies E[T] = 13$.

How ever I am not seeing the pattern of how to set this up:

Given $i$ I should be finding $E[T\mid i]$ which will be a function of $i$.

Comment: Do you wish to generalize this in some way to $k-i$ black balls? Otherwise you can just use polynomial interpolation to get a $\mathbb{E}[T|i]$ as a polynomial $p(i)$. Or even simply write it as a piecewise function

Comment: @JohnWhite yes it would be nice to see a more generalized result. But also would be interested to see how to set this problem up as a polynomial.

Comment: Your computation for $i=1$ is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for a general result, I'll try to get you started with that.

Suppose that there are $i$ white balls, and $n-i$ black balls in the urn.

Now in the case with $k$ black balls, there is a $\frac{k}{n}$ probability that a black ball is picked and replaced with a white ball. Further, with probability $\frac{n-k}{n}$, a white ball is picked and nothing changes.

So,

$$
\mathbb{E}[T | i] = 1 + \frac{n-i}{n}\mathbb{E}[T|i+1] + \frac{i}{n}\mathbb{E}[T | i]
$$

Therefore the recurrence is,

$$
\mathbb{E}[T | i] = \frac{n}{n-i} + \mathbb{E}[T|i+1] 
$$

The base case for $\mathbb{E}[T | n] = 0$ and you want to find $\mathbb{E}[T | 0]$.

Can you take it from here?

Hint: Sum up the terms $\frac{n}{1} + \frac{n}{2} + \cdots + \frac{n}{n}$

Comment: We will get $E[T \mid 0] = n\cdot H_n$ where $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$ .Then we get $E[T\mid i] = n( H_n - \frac{1}{n-1} - ... - \frac{1}{n-i})$. I think I did my arithmetic correctly.

Comment: It should stop at $\frac{1}{n-i+1}$ in your equation. Or simply $\mathbb{E}[T | i] = n \sum_{k=i}^{n-1} \frac{1}{n-k}$